# Java - Suggest Thread Pooling Framework

Tags: java, threadpool

There are Jobs.
Job contain Different Tasks 
Job1 
    - Task 11 
    - Task 12 
    - Task 13 
Job2 
   Task 21 
   Task 22 
   Task 23 
Job3
   Task 31
   Task 32
 
   Task 33
   Task 34
 

I am using Executor framework, and running say 3 task in different threads simeltaneoulsly. But right now there is no way to say those 3 threads run task from 
different job and not from same job.
What I want is some kind of framework, where I can put these task in different buckets based on their job. And when thread activate and run the task it should pick task from different job bucket maybe in round-robin fashion.

Each Job having no interdependency with each other. For some job, it is nacessary to run only 1 task at a time.

Comment: Have you looked at www.quartz-scheduler.org ?

Comment: I am reading its tutorial. Thanks for suggestion. My requirement is not to run those threads at specific timimg, I need something to group those threads based on its job, and Executor framework should run thread from each group. Do I implement this in Quartz

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use multiple executor pools as your buckets?

Comment: hey, thanks for reply. And sorry, I forgot to mentioned one important thing, that task are added at runtime. <br/> Let say if I use multiple executor pool as my bucket, but how I am going to control, that parent executor pool have thread from each of my bucket.